# Is there a way to automate folder optimization type in windows?

Tags: windows, windows-8, script, automation

In windows 7 and 8, the downloads folder become optimized for pictures after a while, it causes the folder to lag when opened and even after changing that it returns to pictures every now and then.

There's a way to fix this: http://www.istartedsomething.com/20121202/quick-fix-for-very-slow-to-load-downloads-folder-in-windows-7-8/

But I want to automate this with a script and the task scheduler.

Is it possible? What commands should be used?

Comment: Weird. I always customize all folders for general Items (including my Downloads folder) and they *never* switch despite what I store in the folder subsequently. Of course from Folder Options > View tab I have the same view applied to all folders, so that may have helped.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Look at the Registry key:

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\Local Settings\Software\Microsoft\Windows\Shell\Bags
```

There are a whole lot of numbers there. They represent special shell object including folders.

Under the `Shell` subkey they can have a `SniffedFolderType` value which is the type Windows thinks is best, or a `FolderType` which is the one you have set in Explorer. It can be `Generic, Pictures, Documents` etc.

You could use reg.exe or other PowerShell to change these values, except I'm not sure the numbers representing the `Downloads` folders are the same for every user and computer. But if you just want to do that for your own user, that should work.

In my case `35` is the Downloads folder, so I can use:

```
REG.exe ADD "HKCU\Software\Classes\Local Settings\Software\Microsoft\Windows\Shell\Bags\35\Shell" /v FolderType /t REG_SZ /d Generic /f
```

Apparently you can also disable the whole sniffing business by adding a new string (REG_SZ) value with the name `FolderType` under:

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\Local Settings\Software\Microsoft\Windows\Shell\Bags\AllFolders\Shell
```

for the data use: `NotSpecified`

Comment: Very nice. How can you find out what number represent which folder?

Comment: I used Process Monitor (https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645) to see which registry keys were changed when I changed the type in Explorer.

Comment: The optimized view plays havoc with Google Drive File Stream forcing it to download all the files in the folder to pull out the metadata, much better the default is set to NotSpecified so folders open instantly.